# Having trouble finding how to position calendar with bootstrap-datetimepicker

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to build a form using bootstrap-datetimepicker for selecting dates, and when using in a bootstrap form, the calendar isn't positioned correctly under textbox, nor is the calendar icon just a small icon next to the text box as if I were to just make a simple datetimepicker as in [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) tutorial.  I'm struggling to find a solution for this.  If anyone can help, I'd greatly appreciate it!

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Rental Car Agreement</h1>
                <img src="../chris_cole">
            </div>
            <section>
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Personal Information:</legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="address">Street Address:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Enter address">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="city">City:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="Enter city">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="state">State:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" placeholder="Enter state">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="zip">Zip Code:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="Enter zip code">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter phone number">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Other Information:</legend>
                        <div class="form-group input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function () {
                                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                            });
                        </script>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
```

[image: my site]

Answer (score 0):

Your nesting of the `input-group` class is incorrect. You should not mix form groups or grid column classes directly with input groups. Instead, nest the input group inside of the form group or grid-related element.
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```